# Get price between 2 dates

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to get the price between 2 dates based on the hotel tariffs.

[image]

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>();
for (var dt = checkIn; dt <= checkOut; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
{
    dates.Add(dt);
}

try
{
    cnn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    cnn.ConnectionString = connString;
    cnn.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        lblResult.Text = "Pass";
        string da = dates[i].Year + "-" + dates[i].Month + "-" + dates[i].Day;
        DayOfWeek da1 = dates[i].DayOfWeek;
        if (dates[i].Day == 1 && dates[i].Month == 1 || dates[i].Day == 9 && dates[i].Month == 1 || dates[i].Day == 11 && dates[i].Month == 2 || dates[i].Day == 20 && dates[i].Month == 3 || dates[i].Day == 29 && dates[i].Month == 4 || dates[i].Day == 3 && dates[i].Month == 5 || dates[i].Day == 4 && dates[i].Month == 5 || dates[i].Day == 5 && dates[i].Month == 5 || dates[i].Day == 17 && dates[i].Month == 7 || dates[i].Day == 11 && dates[i].Month == 8 || dates[i].Day == 18 && dates[i].Month == 9 || dates[i].Day == 22 && dates[i].Month == 9 || dates[i].Day == 9 && dates[i].Month == 10 || dates[i].Day == 3 && dates[i].Month == 11 || dates[i].Day == 23 && dates[i].Month == 11 || dates[i].Day == 23 && dates[i].Month == 12)
        {
            sql = "SELECT GrossPrice FROM HotelPriceFIT WHERE HotelName='" + hotelName + "' AND RmType='" + rmType + "' AND Remarks LIKE '%Eve of Japan Holiday%' AND DATE(StartDate) >='" + da + "' AND DATE(EndDate) <='" + da + "'";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Pass 2');", true);
        }
        else if (da1.ToString() == "Saturday")
        {
            sql = "SELECT GrossPrice FROM HotelPriceFIT WHERE HotelName='" + hotelName + "' AND RmType='" + rmType + "' AND Remarks LIKE '%Sat%' AND DATE(StartDate) >='" + da + "' AND DATE(EndDate) <='" + da + "'";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Pass 3');", true);
        }
        else
        {
            **sql = "SELECT GrossPrice FROM HotelPriceFIT WHERE HotelName='" + hotelName + "' AND RmType='" + rmType + "' AND DATE(StartDate) >='" + da + "' AND DATE(EndDate) <='" + da + "'";**
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Pass 4');", true);
            lblPassHotel.Text = sql;
        }
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cnn);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read() == true)
        {
            amount = amount + reader.GetInt16(0);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    cnn.Close();
}
```

If i select

2018-01-18 as start date and 2018-01-19 as end date, it should return me 9000.

Appreciate any form of support.

Empty set

Comment: The problem is the empty set...

Comment: The sum is calculated separately...

Comment: http://i67.tinypic.com/2yngggn.png

Comment: please use named parameters in your queries. most people will not respond with code answers that promote sql injection because it's such a serious bug.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems here:

1. You need to group this line using `()` brackets. Since you have not grouped you are confusing yourself. Either group all `&&` or group all `||` so final condition is `&&` only (or `||` only)

   ```
   if (dates[i].Day == 1 && dates[i].Month == 1 || dates[i].Day == 9 && dates[i].Month == 1 || dates[i].Day == 11 && dates[i].Month == 2 || dates[i].Day == 20 && dates[i].Month == 3 || dates[i].Day == 29 && dates[i].Month == 4 || dates[i].Day == 3 && dates[i].Month == 5 || dates[i].Day == 4 && dates[i].Month == 5 || dates[i].Day == 5 && dates[i].Month == 5 || dates[i].Day == 17 && dates[i].Month == 7 || dates[i].Day == 11 && dates[i].Month == 8 || dates[i].Day == 18 && dates[i].Month == 9 || dates[i].Day == 22 && dates[i].Month == 9 || dates[i].Day == 9 && dates[i].Month == 10 || dates[i].Day == 3 && dates[i].Month == 11 || dates[i].Day == 23 && dates[i].Month == 11 || dates[i].Day == 23 && dates[i].Month == 12)
   ```

This is the reason, that always last Else condition gets executed.

2. This code is prone to SQL Injection attack. Parameterize your query.

Comment: This code is written as a C# code... will it still be prone to a SQL injection attack?

Comment: Code written in any language are prone to SQL injection attack. Parameterizing your inputs is your best defense.

Comment: @Sunil yes. its not the language, but the fact that you're concatenating strings to build a query that's the problem. if someone hacks one of those strings, they can complete the original sql statement and add a new sql statement in the same string that could compromise your data. Take a look here: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Order of precedence dictates `and` is evaluated before `or`, so I don't *think* the missing parentheses is an issue with that statement.  I agree it would add clarity and is a worthwhile suggestion, and I certainly think there are better ways to do that, but I don't think that's what's wrong.